# Duplicated field when using alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query that extract the competitions available, and my table have a common field called `name` so I used the `alias` for recognize this field in the final result:

```
$query = "SELECT c.*,
c.name AS competition_name,
s.name AS season_name
FROM competition c
LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON c.id = s.competition_id
WHERE country_id = :country_id";
```

the problem's that the query will return the field `name`:

```
 {
    "id": "1093",
    "country_id": "1",
    "name": "Premier League",
    "category": "1",
    "competition_name": "Premier League",
    "season_name": "2018"
}
```

that is a duplication of `competition_name`, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `SELECT c.*`, which includes `c.name`:

Your query expands to:

```
SELECT 
     c.id, c.country_id, c.name, c.category, 
     c.name AS competition_name, s.name AS season_name 
FROM ...
```

so you `SELECT` the `name` field twice.

Comment: mmm but I specified `c.name as competition_name`

Comment: Yes, but you `SELECT` the field twice, once in `c.*`, and once in `c.name AS competition_name`.

Comment: Yes, using `SELECT *` is bad practice anyway: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I did not know, I always thought that selecting all the fields manually was a problem for the performance, this thing was also told by a senior programmer, but apparently he was wrong, thank you.